# Is there a way I can append a href link in Jquery to show different pages after the link has been pressed?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way I can append a href link in jquery to show different pages after the link is pressed?

Here is my code for it

```
<a id="reveal" href="happycharacterone.php">Reveal</a>
```

What I want to do is each time I press the link I want a new page to show up is that something that can be achieved?

Comment: you can use `localStorage` for that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got the question right, anyway, here's my attempt:

```js
var links = ['happycharacterone.php', 'happycharactertwo.php', 'happycharacterthree.php'];
var index = 0;

$('#reveal').on('click', function(e) {
  index = (index + 1) % links.length;
  $(this).attr('href', links[index]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="reveal" target="_blank" href="happycharacterone.php">Reveal</a>
```

Note: The links don't open in this example because the popups are being stopped, but it should work fine in your project.

Comment: You must explain that's randomed URL set, but my upvote because that's fine

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will add your code to my project and let you know if it works.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude you are right. In my example the url's change randomly, do you want them in a specific order?

Comment: I just want them to be when I press the link it will change to the next page e.g happycharactertwo.php and so on. is that possible to achieve with the random url mentioned above?

Comment: @L.Russell I changed so that it goes from happycharacterone to happycharacterthree and then it starts again.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out and adjust it if needs be.

Comment: I tested it and it works fine but I was wondering if I wanted to add more links to the page e.g happycharacterfour.php then I will just add to the links part right is that correct? @Jonas Grumann

Comment: Is there a way it can change so that when I refresh the page and I click it then it shows the page?

Comment: Usually, to make things work after a refresh you need to use a server side language. You could do it with js by appending a 'get' parameter to the url (example: www.yoursite.com/?url=happycharacterfour.php ) but this goes a little bit out of the scope of the question. To add a new link just add it in the links array, like you mentioned above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124863/discussion-between-l-russell-and-jonas-grumann).

Comment: Hi Jonas, is there a way to just make it go from 1 to 2 then 2 to 3 and so on because at the moment it goes straight to two rather than going to one. I want it a way where I I press the reveal button and it will show one, then if I close and go back to it and do the same process and I press 2 it will show happycharactertwo.php is that possible to do?

Comment: Yes it's possible. The code is straightforward, you should be able to implement it on your own by changing what I gave you. Sorry but this is taking too long, I'm not a freelance programmer.